# Two different generic types as result and parameter

Tags: c#, generics

With this method I can return unknown data type :

```
private T Call<T>(Uri uri) where T:new()  { }
```

But how to pass an another unknown data type (not the same) as parameter :

```
private T Call<T>(Uri uri, ??? parameters) where T:new()  { }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has zero or close to it value for future visitors. The question is apparently how to use more than one generic parameter for a .NET type. This is detailed in the documentation for generics, and thus hold little value for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another generic type parameter:

```
private T Call<T, TOther>(Uri uri, TOther parameters) where T:new()  { }
```